# how to prevent sequence when i use Array.forEach

Tags: javascript

```
const a = {};
array.forEach(item => {
  a[item.id] = item;
})
```

when i get `a`, I found it was sort by `item.id`.  How to prevent the sort when `forEach`.
if `array = [{id: 2}, {id: 6}, {id : 1}]`, and then I get `a = {1: {id: 1}, 2: {id: 2}, 6: {id: 6}}`. 
my want is `a={2: {id: 2}, 6: {id：6}, 1: {id: 1}}`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can enforce a particular object key sequence in JS. You can, however, create an array of the keys.

```
const a = {};
const originalSequence = [];
array.forEach(item => {
   a[item.id] = item;
   originalSequence.push(item.id);
})
```

Comment: my want is 'a', 'originalSequence' has no use.